# Is there a way to find a file by just its name in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5

We use absolut path or relatvie path to find a file in our C# application right now. Is there a way to find the file just by its name if the file is under the  currect working directory or under one of the "paths"?

Use absolute pathe is not good and use relative path is not good enough because we may change project structure by rename or move project folders. If we our code can automatically search current working directory, its subfolders and search system path, that will be more flexible.

thanks,

Comment: What happens if there is more than one matching file under current directory?  In searching system path (if not found under current dir) will you just use the first match?

Comment: yes, search current dir first then system path, always return the first found. .Net doesn't has existing code available to use?

Comment: Not a single method - but you should be able to combine answers below to implement this as 1) find match under current and 2) scan system path if no match in 1). For 1), I don't see that you need to do your own recursion - .Net already has EnumerateFiles to scan a subtree for matching file(s). You may need to crack the system path and iterate its members in 2) though.

Comment: I've tried to provide an answer for what I think you are trying to do below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
string target = "yourFilenameToMatch";
string current = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

// 1. check subtree from current directory
matches=Directory.GetFiles(current, target, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
if (matches.Length>0)
    return matches[0];

// 2. check system path
string systemPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH");
char[] split = new char[] {";"};
foreach (string nextDir in systemPath.Split(split))
{
    if (File.Exists(nextDir + '\\' + target)
    {
        return nextDir;
    }
}

return String.Empty;
```

Comment: For me, the "SYSTEMROOT" resolves to C:\Windows.  It looks like you mean to get the "PATH" environment variable instead... ?

Answer (score 3):

You can easily build a recursive function to do this for you. Look at Directory.GetDirectories and Directory.GetFiles, both under System.IO

Comment: There's a sample on MSDN showing you exactly how to do this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513869.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could call [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx) for each root folder in which you want to search for the file. the parameter searchOption allow you to specify whether the search operation look in all subdirectories or only the directory specified. E.g:

```
public string GetFileName(string[] folders,string fileName) {
    string[] filePaths;
    foreach(var folder in folders) {
        filePaths=Directory.GetFiles(folder,fileName,SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        if (filePaths.Lenght>0)
            return filePaths[0];
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(pathInWhichToSearch, fileNameToFind, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

And, you need to use:

```
using System.IO;
```

on top of your class.

This searches all subdirectories of `pathInWhichToSearch` for a file with name `fileNameToFind` (it can be a pattern too - like `*.txt`) and returns result as `IEnumerable<string>` with full paths of found files.

Comment: are you using .net 4? there is no EnumerateFiles in my .net 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the exe's directory using

`Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);`

Example  Code: http://www.csharp-examples.net/get-application-directory/

And then, you can search the folders from there using recursion. This is a good article on recursive searching for files:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303974